# Quel nom composé de « traction » ou autrement exprime le mieux le « muscle up » ?

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, terminologie, sport

> *Traction complète à la barre fixe.
>  Traction suivi d'une répulsion
> à la barre fixe*.

---

- Lequel trouve-t-on le meilleur pour signifier le « [muscle up](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=MUSCLE%20UP&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) »
  (en « [gymnastique](https://youtu.be/pzDAxasj1-8) ») et pourquoi ?
- A-t-on une meilleure idée (hormis l'emprunt intégral) ?

Answer (score 1):

Selon wiki: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle-up :

> Le muscle-up (**de l'angl. muscle-up pouvant être traduit en traction complète ou en par-dessus**) est un mouvement inséparable du street workout, de la gymnastique, du crossfit et de la callisthénie où le pratiquant poursuit une traction jusqu'à ce que son tronc dépasse la barre, les bras tendus.

Je fais de la callisthénie et je trouve que muscle-up est assez répandu.

Même domyos l'utilise :
https://www.domyos.fr/reussir-le-muscle-up-make-the-rigth-move

> Le muscle-up est une combinaison technique de deux mouvements de
> musculation à poids de corps: les tractions et les dips.
>
> En effet, le but est de passer au dessus de la barre (transition*) à
> la suite de la traction* afin d’effectuer un dips* et terminer bras
> tendus au dessus de la barre.
>
> L’exercice se décompose en 3 mouvements :
>
> • la traction* : je tire mon corps vers le haut, derrière la barre (et
> non sous la barre comme une traction classique)
>
> • la transition : je fais passer le corps au dessus de la barre fixe
>
> • la répulsion ou dips : je pousse sur les bras pour arriver jusqu’en
> haut